# How to configure phpmailer in redhat AMI to avoid PHPMailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmailer, redhat

I have developed a PHP and MySQL webapp which also uses phpmailer..It ran without any errors when I used it in my WAMP. But When I uploaded my site to online server via EC2 instance in aws and picking redhat AMI..And everything was going well until I found that my published site won't send any mails..Instead it returns an error saying `Message was not sent.PHPMailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`..

Few info regarding my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = "something@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "PWofsomething";
$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.
$mail->From = "something@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "something";
$mail->addAddress(validemail,validfirstname);
$mail->Subject = "bla bla bla";
$mail->Body = html body
if(!$mail->Send()){
  echo "Message was not sent."<br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo."<br />";
   }
else{
echo 'success';
  $mail->clearAddresses();
`
```

*PS*:I could add few more .conf or .ini files if you want

Comment: Please search SO for that message, it's been answered many times. Also, [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: I already did..but most of them were off my topic...They were all trying to fix the problem saying to include dynamic php_smtp.dll extension..But i Think its for win32..And mine is redhat 7.2@Synchro

Comment: Seriously, look harder.

Comment: I read this [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/335) and also others which it leads to..What I understand is that google is getting concious and may be its the reason when my website is trying to send mails using a gmail account, it fails..retruning `SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.`..@Synchro

Comment: What should I do? To solve this?

Comment: Exactly this problem is covered in the guide. You can also use xoauth2 if you read the wiki